# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Connection refused

Tags: java, cloud, cloud-foundry, pcf

I've seen the error below upon cf push. I have created an "External Dependency" with several IP addresses. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
Staging...
[DownloadCache] WARN Unable to download http://tools.<sensitive-hostname>/icarus-cf-download/jbp_versions/v3.12-repo-v1/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/index.yml into cache /tmp: Failed to open TCP connection to https://approxy.<sensitive-hostname>:8443 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "https://approxy.<sensitive-hostname>" port 8443)
[Buildpack] ERROR Compile failed with exception #<RuntimeError: Open JDK Like Memory Calculator error: Unable to find cached file for http://tools<sensitive-hostname>/icarus-cf-download/jbp_versions/v3.12-repo-v1/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/index.yml>
Open JDK Like Memory Calculator error: Unable to find cached file for http://tools<sensitive-hostname>/icarus-cf-download/jbp_versions/v3.12-repo-v1/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/index.yml
Failed to compile droplet
Exit status 223
```

Comment: They suggested me to create an "external dependency" covering several IP addresses and ports.

Comment: Sorry but _"an "external dependency" covering several IP addresses "_ does not make any sense.  Can you clarify what you mean by "external dependency", maybe show exactly how you did that?

Comment: @Perugini it would probably be best to not post hostnames of internal resources. I've edited your post to that effect, but I can't do anything about the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure your security groups to allow access to pull resources from external network.

Refer [ASG](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-0/concepts/asg.html#introduction)